# Responsive Web Design when viewed on iPad is missing components

Tags: ipad, responsive-design, missing-features

I am fairly new to responsive web design and am looking for guidance. My problem lays with a missing component. I have a footer that is fixed to the bottom with social media icons, and when I resize it on the desktop to an iPad size, they are visible. However, when I go on an actual iPad, the icons are missing.

If I refresh quick enough on the iPad, I can see the borders I put on them underneath the footer, so I play with the z-index. No luck. I thought perhaps it was a browser thing, but still no luck.

Am I overlooking something?

Here is the testing site: 
http://liannesuggitt.com/test/portfolio/

And when viewed on multiple sizes:

http://ami.responsivedesign.is/?url=http://www.liannesuggitt.com/test/portfolio/

If either of these are viewed on an actual iPad, the icons in the footer are gone.

I am using media queries, if that helps.

Thanks for any help,

Comment: I think your problems origin are the `position: fixed` and the `z-index` properties...  
In my opinion this issue could be solved if you move the `footer`'s content in to the `bar`.

Comment: Yes! Thank you Bamee, that fixed it! Now for some tweaking to get the "bar" 100% of the screen again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Retina iPad? Also, have you viewed the site in a browser window that mimicks the same resolution (width) as the iPad. If so, what browser & did the footer icons still go missing? This will determine if the issue is iPad specific or an issue with the media queries themselves.

Comment: It is not a retina iPad, and when shrunk down to the width of an iPad in Firefox, the icons are still there. Same with Safri, Icons are still there.

Comment: Bamee I will try that too, hold on (I'm a bit slow at this still)